# inconsistent variable when passing it from one method to another

Tags: java, inputstream

I have a problem that I have not been able to solve and it does not occur to me that it could be.

I have a class to which I am passing an InputStream from the main method, the problem is that when transforming the InputString to String with the class IOUtils.toString of AWS, or with the IOUtils of commons-io, they return
  an empty String
No matter what the problem may be, since inside the main class, it works correctly and returns the String it should, but when I use it inside the other class (without having done anything), it returns the empty String to me.

these are my classes:

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {

        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("{\"name\":\"Camilo\",\"functionName\":\"hello\"}".getBytes());
        OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        LambdaExecutor lambdaExecutor = new LambdaExecutor();


        String test = IOUtils.toString(inputStream); //this test variable have "{\"name\":\"Camilo\",\"functionName\":\"hello\"}"
        lambdaExecutor.handleRequest(inputStream,outputStream);
    }
}
```

and this:

```
    public class LambdaExecutor{

    private FrontController frontController;
    public LambdaExecutor(){
        this.frontController = new FrontController();
    }

    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        //Service service = frontController.findService(inputStream);

        String test = IOUtils.toString(inputStream); //this test variable have "" <-empty String

        System.exit(0);
        //service.execute(inputStream, outputStream, context);
    }
}
```

I used the debug tool, and the InputStream object is the same in both classes

Comment: It would seem to me you've already consumed the stream by the time you pass it into handleRequest(). What happens if you pass it without the first test?

Comment: @NAMS i was just about  to say the exact same thing. Go and write it as an answer. You solved it before me

Comment: @NAMS You are right. I just debugged the code with out the first test It is working fine. Anyway let's wait for OP comment.

Comment: now it works, you are right. How could I prevent this from happening? I must use that InputStream in a couple of classes that analyze it.

Comment: @kmilo93sd Assuming that you're eventually going to be reading from a file or some other source, you'll have to close the stream and re-open it.

Comment: Bit out of context: If you ae using latest version of common.io then  `IOUtils.toString(inputStream)` has been marked as deprecated. You can use new method `IOUtils.toString(inputStream,charsetEncoding)`

Comment: @Kmilo93sd No you don't have to close and reopen it. Just turn it into a string first only once and then pass the String around and not the stream...

Comment: Thank you very much, could you reply to the post to mark it as correct? You have solved my question very clearly, the problem was the one you indicated.

Comment: @kmilo93sd i replied and added you the solution if you want to be passing it around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time that you've passed the stream into `handleRequest()`, you've already consumed the stream:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("{\"name\":\"Camilo\",\"functionName\":\"hello\"}".getBytes());
    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    LambdaExecutor lambdaExecutor = new LambdaExecutor();


    String test = IOUtils.toString(inputStream); //this consumes the stream, and nothing more can be read from it
    lambdaExecutor.handleRequest(inputStream,outputStream);
}
```

When you took that out, the method worked as, as you said in the comments.

If you want the data to be re-useable, you'll have to use the `reset()` method if you want the same data again, or close and re-open the stream to re-use the object with different data.

```
// have your data 
byte[] data = "{\"name\":\"Camilo\",\"functionName\":\"hello\"}".getBytes();
// open the stream
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
...
// do something with the inputStream, and reset if you need the same data again
if(inputStream.markSupported()) {
    inputStream.reset();
} else {
    inputStream.close();
    inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
}
...
// close the stream after use
inputStream.close();
```

Always close the stream after you use it, or use a try block to take advantage of `AutoCloseable`; you can do the same with the output stream:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    lambdaExecutor.handleRequest(inputStream, outputStream);
} // auto-closed the streams
```

Comment: Not every input stream can be reset(). Check my answer.

Comment: Of course! That's only fair. Do you know of an instance where reset() wouldn't work?

Comment: I just read that it might be those that are connected to sockets can only once be read, but here he should  be okay i think. You can also put print to check if it works in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can't is because you can only read from a stream once.

To be able to read twice, you must call the `reset()` method for it to return to the beginning. After reading, call `reset()` and you can read it again!

Some sources don't support resetting it so you would actually have to create the stream again. To check if the source supports it, use the `markSupported()` method of the stream!